# Fancy example environment

Tags: environments

How do create a colourful example environment like the one here?

[image]

Comment: that is a simple colored table

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Below I present two options, both of them admitting page breaks.

1. A simple example using [`tcolorbox`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/tcolorbox) (admits page breaks); adjust the settings according to your needs:

   [image]

   The code:

   ```
   \documentclass{article}
   \usepackage{lipsum}
   \usepackage[many]{tcolorbox}

   \definecolor{greentitle}{RGB}{61,170,61}
   \definecolor{greentitleback}{RGB}{216,233,213}

   \newtcolorbox[
     auto counter,
     number within=section
   ]{myexample}[2][]{%
     breakable,
     enhanced,
     colback=white,
     colbacktitle=white,
     arc=0pt,
     leftrule=1pt,
     rightrule=0pt,
     toprule=0pt,
     bottomrule=0pt,
     titlerule=0pt,
     colframe=greentitleback,
     fonttitle=\normalcolor,
     overlay={
       \node[
         outer sep=0pt,
         anchor=east,
         text width=2.5cm,
         minimum height=4ex,
         fill=greentitleback,
         font=\color{greentitle}\sffamily\scshape
       ] at (title.west) {example~\thetcbcounter};
     },
     title=#2,
     #1
   }
   \newcommand\Solution{\par\textbf{\textsf{Solution}}\par\medskip}

   \begin{document}

   \section{A test section}
   \begin{myexample}{Factorise $x^2-2x+1$}
   \Solution
    \lipsum[4]
   \end{myexample}

   \end{document}
   ```
2. A simple example using [`mdframed`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/mdframed) (admits page breaks); adjust the settings according to your needs:

   [image]

   The code:

   ```
   \documentclass{article}
   \usepackage{chngcntr}
   \usepackage[tikz]{mdframed}
   \usepackage{lipsum}

   \definecolor{greentitle}{RGB}{61,170,61}
   \definecolor{greentitleback}{RGB}{216,233,213}

   \newcounter{mdexample}
   \counterwithin{mdexample}{section}

   \newenvironment{myexample}[1]
     {\stepcounter{mdexample}\begin{mdframed}[
       frametitle=#1,
       frametitlefont=\normalfont,
       topline=false,
       bottomline=false,
       rightline=false,
       linecolor=greentitleback,
       linewidth=2pt,
       singleextra={
         \node[
           overlay,
           outer sep=0pt,
           anchor=north east,
           text width=2.5cm,
           minimum height=4ex,
           fill=greentitleback,
           font=\color{greentitle}\sffamily\scshape
         ] at (O|-P) {example~\themdexample};
         },
       firstextra={
         \node[
           overlay,
           outer sep=0pt,
           anchor=north east,
           text width=2.5cm,
           minimum height=4ex,
           fill=greentitleback,
           font=\color{greentitle}\sffamily\scshape
         ] at (O|-P) {example~\themdexample};
         }
       ]
     }
     {\end{mdframed}}
   \newcommand\Solution{\par\textbf{\textsf{Solution}}\par\medskip}

   \begin{document}

   \section{A test section}
   \begin{myexample}{Factorise $x^2-2x+1$}
   \Solution
    \lipsum[4]
   \end{myexample}

   \end{document}
   ```

Comment: @Gauss You're welcome! I did some improvements to the code in my updated answer that might be of interest for you.

Comment: @Gauss Now I added another option to my answer, using this time `mdframed`.

Comment: @cfr No problem. I've deleted my previous comment, and I will delete this one soon.

Comment: How can I put the word example out of the box?

Comment: Hi Gonzalo, thanks for your awesome answer here. I would like to modify your example environment so that the green "example" box is on the right side of the vertical line. I opened a new question, if you have time to take a look. Thank you in advance!
 https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/603869/kaobook-example-environment-with-vertical-line