# Custom example environment with colorbox and vertical line for `kaobook` document class

Tags: formatting, environments, books, examples, kaobook

I am making a custom example environment for the `kaobook` class and would like to modify the second example environment from [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/212943/fancy-example-environment):

[image: ![enter image description here]

```
\usepackage{chngcntr}
\usepackage[tikz]{mdframed}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\definecolor{greentitle}{RGB}{61,170,61}
\definecolor{greentitleback}{RGB}{216,233,213}

\newcounter{mdexample}
\counterwithin{mdexample}{section}

\newenvironment{myexample}[1]
  {\stepcounter{mdexample}\begin{mdframed}[
    frametitle=#1,
    frametitlefont=\normalfont,
    topline=false,
    bottomline=false,
    rightline=false,
    linecolor=greentitleback,
    linewidth=2pt,
    singleextra={
      \node[
        overlay,
        outer sep=0pt,
        anchor=north east,
        text width=2.5cm,
        minimum height=4ex,
        fill=greentitleback,
        font=\color{greentitle}\sffamily\scshape
      ] at (O|-P) {example~\themdexample};
      },
    firstextra={
      \node[
        overlay,
        outer sep=0pt,
        anchor=north east,
        text width=2.5cm,
        minimum height=4ex,
        fill=greentitleback,
        font=\color{greentitle}\sffamily\scshape
      ] at (O|-P) {example~\themdexample};
      }
    ]
  }
  {\end{mdframed}}
```

I would like to modify the environment so that:

- I would like the green "Example" box to be on the right side of the vertical line, not in the margin.
- I would like there to be a gap between the green "Example" box and the vertical line, instead of being connected to the vertical line.
- I would also like there to be a "title" for the example, similar to
  this. (e.g. title: "Evaluating a Function")

If it helps, here is a link to the [Overleaf project.](https://www.overleaf.com/3212563377jyzdcgshhhbn) Feel free to edit it.

---

**Edit:** Thank you Alan Xiang for your solution!

[image]

I am wondering if it is possible to share numbering with theorems and other kaoboxes? I tried to change `\newcounter{examplecounter}\counterwithin{examplecounter}{section}` to `\numberwithin{kaocounter}{section}` but this didn't work.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let me know if this is what you are looking for. It also supports breaking the box across multiple pages.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[skins,hooks,xparse,breakable]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{chngcntr}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{tikz}

\newcounter{examplecounter}
\counterwithin{examplecounter}{section}

\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\definecolor{greentitle}{RGB}{61,170,61}
\definecolor{greentitleback}{RGB}{216,233,213}
\definecolor{drakgreentitle}{RGB}{24,131,80}

\DeclareTColorBox{bookexample}{O{}}{
    enhanced,
    breakable,
    arc=0pt,
    boxrule=0pt,
    colback=white,
    before skip={2em}, % increase spacing before the env
    overlay unbroken and first={
        % draw box on the left
        \node[fill=greentitleback,
            font=\color{greentitle}\sffamily\bfseries\large,
            anchor=south west,
            xshift=2mm
        ] (titlebox) at (frame.north west) 
        {Exercise \refstepcounter{examplecounter}\theexamplecounter};
        
        % write title on the right
        \node[font=\color{drakgreentitle}\sffamily\large, 
        anchor=west
        ] at ($(titlebox.east)+(2mm,0mm)$) {#1};
        
        % draw the vertical line on the left
        \draw[draw=greentitleback, line width=2pt] 
            (titlebox.north west-|frame.north west)--(frame.south west);
    },
    overlay middle and last={
        \draw[draw=greentitleback, line width=2pt] 
            (frame.north west)--(frame.south west);
    }
    fonttitle=\color{greentitle}\sffamily\bfseries,
}

\DeclareTColorBox{genericbox}{m}{
    enhanced,
    breakable,
    arc=0pt,
    boxrule=0pt,
    colback=white,
    attach boxed title to top left,
    boxed title style={
        colback=white,
        colframe=white,
    },
    title={#1},
    fonttitle=\color{greentitle}\sffamily\bfseries\large
}

\begin{document}

\section{First Section}

\null
\begin{bookexample}[My Title]
\Blindtext[4]
\end{bookexample}

\begin{genericbox}{Solution}
\Blindtext[2]
\end{genericbox}

\section{Second Section}

\null
\begin{bookexample}[Another Title]
\Blindtext[4]
\end{bookexample}

\begin{genericbox}{Solution}
\Blindtext[2]
\end{genericbox}

% No title
\begin{bookexample}
\Blindtext[1]
\end{bookexample}

\end{document}
```

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[skins,hooks,xparse,breakable]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{chngcntr}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{tikz}

% comment this line during integration because kaocounter would have been declared
\newcounter{kaocounter}
% you may not need the line below as well if it has already been configured using other approaches
\counterwithin{kaocounter}{section}

\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\definecolor{greentitle}{RGB}{61,170,61}
\definecolor{greentitleback}{RGB}{216,233,213}
\definecolor{drakgreentitle}{RGB}{24,131,80}

\DeclareTColorBox{bookexample}{O{}o}{
    enhanced,
    breakable,
    arc=0pt,
    boxrule=0pt,
    colback=white,
    top=3em, % you can change the top spacing
    overlay unbroken and first={
        % draw box on the left
        \node[fill=greentitleback,
            font=\color{greentitle}\sffamily\bfseries\large,
            anchor=south west,
            xshift=2mm,
            yshift=-2em, % you can change xshift and yshift to adjust the title placement
        ] (titlebox) at (frame.north west) 
        % notice the difference here, kaocounter is used instead
        {Exercise \refstepcounter{kaocounter}\thekaocounter
        % add cross-referencing support
        \IfValueT{#2}{\label{#2}}
        };
        
        % write title on the right
        \node[font=\color{drakgreentitle}\sffamily\large, 
        anchor=west
        ] at ($(titlebox.east)+(2mm,0mm)$) {#1};
        
        % draw the vertical line on the left
        \draw[draw=greentitleback, line width=2pt] 
            (titlebox.north west-|frame.north west)--(frame.south west);
    },
    overlay middle and last={
        \draw[draw=greentitleback, line width=2pt] 
            (frame.north west)--(frame.south west);
    }
    fonttitle=\color{greentitle}\sffamily\bfseries,
}

\DeclareTColorBox{genericbox}{m}{
    enhanced,
    breakable,
    arc=0pt,
    boxrule=0pt,
    colback=white,
    attach boxed title to top left,
    boxed title style={
        colback=white,
        colframe=white,
    },
    title={#1},
    fonttitle=\color{greentitle}\sffamily\bfseries\large
}

\begin{document}

\section{First Section}

\begin{bookexample}[My Title]
\Blindtext[4]
\end{bookexample}

\begin{genericbox}{Solution}
\Blindtext[2]
\end{genericbox}

\section{Second Section}

% an example with label
\begin{bookexample}[Another Title][ex:one]
\Blindtext[4]
\end{bookexample}

\begin{genericbox}{Solution}
\Blindtext[2]
\end{genericbox}

\textbf{I want to refer to Exercise \ref{ex:one}}.

% No title
\begin{bookexample}
\Blindtext[1]
\end{bookexample}

% No title, but has label
\begin{bookexample}[][ex:two]
\Blindtext[1]
\end{bookexample}

\textbf{I want to refer to Exercise \ref{ex:two}}.

\end{document}
```

Comment: Hi Alan, thank you for your solution! Is it possible to share numbering with theorems and other kaoboxes? I tried to change `\newcounter{examplecounter}\counterwithin{examplecounter}{section}` to `\numberwithin{kaocounter}{section}` but this didn't work. Also wondering if this can support labeling & referencing? I tried `\label{example2}` and `\ref{example2}` but it only printed "1.1" instead of "1.1.2". Also it needs a tiny bit more padding at the top.  updated the original question with a new screenshot -- notice how the example box is touching the yellow theorem box above it.) Thanks again!

Comment: @EthanAlvaree I have modified the code, see the second code listing. The counter is referenced and incremented in the definition of `bookexample`, therefore changing to `\numberwithin{kaocounter}{section}` would not work. In the new example, I have assumed that the counter you are working with is `kaocounter`. I added a second optional argument for cross-referencing support. I also changed the layout of the box so that the top spacing is more controllable. You can change `top` and `yshift` to adjust the header position (see more in code comments).

Comment: Hi Alan, thank you! Everything is working except counter is not shared between Definition, Theorem, Example, etc. Any ideas what I am doing wrong? You are welcome to test out ideas in the Overleaf, if that would help. Thank you again. https://www.overleaf.com/3212563377jyzdcgshhhbn

Comment: I changed the definition of the environment and some settings in `styles/mdftheorems.sty`, now theorem, definition and example share the same counter.

Comment: It worked! Thank you!!

Comment: Everything looks amazing! Does mathematicians have a crush on Palatino fonts in general?  I think it is a little bit too wide.

Comment: Hi Alan! If you have time, I opened a follow-up question about how to print lists of definitions, theorems, examples, etc. at the front of the book: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/606098/list-of-definitions-list-of-theorems-list-of-examples-and-list-of-activities